# Wake up the screen if device detects the shake event

Tags: android, sensors, shake

I'm registering the sensor after the screen sleeps.I have to wake up the screen if device detects the shake event.
If i connect the device with the system, device wakes up correctly.
if i disconnect the device, 
moto g device, chroma tablet  doesn't wake up. But samsung device wakes up.

So that I have tested by displaying the logcat value in textview.
I found the following problems:
Sometimes after screen off, i didn't receive the broadcast message.
Sometimes i receive the message, but maccel values didn't increase after shaking the device also.

I'm using the following code:

**For initialising sensor manager:**

```
manager=(SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
sensor=manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
```

**Registering Broadcast receiver:**

```
registerReceiver(screenoffreceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));
```

**Broadcast receiver :**

```
private BroadcastReceiver screenoffreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF.equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction())) {
                //screen has been switched off!
                manager.registerListener(Testing.this, manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

            }
        }
    };
```

**For Detecting shake event:**

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
          float x = event.values[0];
          float y = event.values[1];
          float z = event.values[2];
          mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
          mAccelCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x*x + y*y + z*z));
          float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
          mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta; // perform low-cut filter
          Log.i("mAccel", "mAccel "+mAccel);

          mytext.setText(mytext.getText().toString()+" "+mAccel);

            if(mAccel>=1) {
                unlock_screen();
            }
```

Please help me to resolve these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i connect the device with system after device locks , the cpu keeps running. So device wakes up when i call  unlock_screen() method.
If i disconnect the device , after it goes to lock mode, the cpu doesn't run.So device doesn't wakes up always when i call  unlock_screen() method.
So I have  Used the **PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK** in order to run the Cpu.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that your service is not killed/reclaimed by the OS you need to make it a foreground service. By default all services are background, meaning they will be killed when the OS needs resources. For details refer to this doc

Basically, you need to create a Notification for your service and indicate that it is foreground. This way the user will see a persistent notification so he knows your app is running, and the OS will not kill your service.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SomeActivityInYourApp));
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

builder.setSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.my_icon);
builder.setTicker("App info string");
builder.setContentIntent(pi);
builder.setOngoing(true);
builder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);

Notification notification = builder.build();

// optionally set a custom view

startForeground(SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: I'm not using service here.I'm registering the sensorListener in the Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: then try with service :) Your Broadcast Receiver want work when the activity is paused. Or if you not unregister the Receiver onPause it is a memory leak ...

Comment: i used broadcast receiver for detecting screen off, Mostly, i receive the broadcast message.Sometimes it fails.Also In some devices even i reset the mAccel,mAccelLast ,mAccelCurrent values after the maccel values reaches >=1,I got the same mAccel values after unregistering and registering the sensor.If i print the sensor event values in logcat .I got the previous x,y,z values.It is not resetting.